# Numerical Key board is not working in 18.04

Tags: numpad

I am using dell inspiron. In this laptop built with  UBUNTU18.04 os. When i install the os from at that time my numerical keys are not working. How to resolve this problem. please reply me as early as possible.

Comment: Which model of Dell Inspiron? Is there a Num Lock button on the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Simple search for "Universal Access" using the global search.

You should then disable "Mouse Keys" at the "Universal Access" configuration.